# $this->__construct() in parent class calling the construct of the child class?

Tags: php

I have two classes, a `ParentClass` and a `ChildClass`.

The parent class looks has two public methods, it's construct and a function that calls its construct.

```php
class ParentClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo '<br>Parent construct<br>';
    }
    
    public function saySomething()
    {
        $this->__construct();
    }
}
```

The `ChildClass` extends `ParentClass` and has its own construct that accepts an `int`.

```php
class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    public function __construct(int $a)
    {
        echo '<br>Child construct, param: '. $a .'<br>';
    }
}
```

Considering how simple those classes are, they work as expected:

```php
$parent = new ParentClass();
$child = new ChildClass(5);
```

```html
Parent Construct

Child Construct, param: 5
```

Works good, until I do the following:

```php
$child->saySomething();
```

```html
FATAL ERROR Uncaught ArgumentCountError: 
Too few arguments to function ChildClass::__construct(), 
0 passed in file.php(4) : 
eval()'d code on line 12 and exactly 1 expected in file.php(4) : 
eval()'d code:18 Stack trace: #0 file.php(4) : 
eval()'d code(12): ChildClass->__construct() #1 file.php(4) : 
eval()'d code(26): ParentClass->saySomething() #2 file.php(4): 
eval() #3 {main} thrown on line number 18
```

It's calling the `ChildClass`'s construct when I placed it in the `ParentClass`?

Also the error states that it eval'd `ParentClass->saySomething()`, so why is it not calling the `ParentClass->__construct()`?

I'm confused by this one.

Comment: You're really abusing constructors there. You should never need to call `$this->__construct()`. Consider moving that `echo` line into a separate method

Comment: Also a method/function should never output any result, return the output to the caller instead

Comment: Try `parent::__construct()` instead. `$this->` always refers to the instantiated class/object. Your use case is a bit muddled though, and agreed with @Phil on how not to use constructors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never use the constructor like this. If you want to instantiate an object with a function, try using `static function` which returns `new self()` object

Second - a `childClass` extended your parent function `saySomething` but implemented it's own `__construct`. So if you call `$childClass->saySomething()` it references to `childClass` constructor. If you really want to call parent constructor you may use `new parent()`

Also try to read about difference between `self` and `static` modifiers